# Try and except exit error after executing the except line

Tags: try-catch, exit, except

I am trying to exit out of the program after executing the except line. I have tried `sys.exit(1)` but it is not working. I am opening an .txt file and and passing it through the code. The code works perfectly. I am just trying to exit out of the code if the wrong file is input like **temp** file rather then **temp.txt**.

```
# Ask input from the user
fname = input("Enter File Name: ")

# Open the file and check if entry is valid
try:
    temp_file = open(fname)
except:
    print("File cannot be opened:", fname)
    # I NEED YOUR HELP HERE
    quit()
    
count = 0
total = 0
    
for temp in temp_file:
    # Remove white space
    temp = temp.strip()
    # Find the exact string
    if temp.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        # Find the position of the number and convert to float
        pos = temp.find(":")
        float_pos = float(temp[pos+1:])
        # Add the numbers and count the number of lines
        total += float_pos
        count += 1
# Print out the average 
print("Average spam confidence: ", total/count)
```